# Where’s that or where is it?

Tags: american-english

I just have a quick question regarding the use of ‘that’ and ‘is’. When someone tells you about a place, for instance a dental office, do you say where’s that? Or where is it? to ask about the location.

Comment: Either. Both are used frequently.

Comment: You're confusing verbs and pronouns.  "Where's" is a contraction for "where is", and one can be substituted for the other with relative impunity.  "That" (in your example) and "it" are pronouns, and can be used somewhat interchangeably (understanding that "that" is over there, whereas "it" has an indeterminate position).  So the choice of "where's" vs "where is" is independent of the choice between "that" and "it".

Comment: However trite this seems, could you reconsider "Where’s that" or "where is it" or bopth to show a useful comparison?

Answer (score 1):

Some additional comments to @Dan Bron's comment

> Either. Both are used frequently. – Dan Bron

I agree that both are used frequently, but if I were to distinguish between the two:

### Example of "Where's that?"

> "So can you make it to the event at (something something) park?"
>
> "Where's *that*?"

### Example of "Where is it?"

> "Are you at the park yet?"
>
> "Not yet. I'm having trouble finding it. Where *is* it?"

### Explanation

"Where is that?" contains a nuance that the person who mentioned the place has a responsibility to explain it more to you:

> "Where is that? (I've never heard of it. You should explain it to me so
> we're on the same page.)"

"That" is more directed that "it", so "that" is used to imply that the place in question is not associated with you (because you don't know about it yet) and that it's more associated with the person you're talking to (because he/she knows about it)

"Where is it?" is used when you and the person you're talking to both know about the place, but you're simply having trouble finding it.

Answer (score 1):

They mean the same but are "pragmatically" different. "Where's that?" refers to what the person mentioned in a sentence. The "that" pronoun refers to the other person's mentioning of a thing in their speech.

WHEREAS:

"Where is it?
refers to the object (referent) in the real world the person referred to. These differences are important if one wants to understand this [ahem] in English conversational patterns.